# Django: adding cc in email with sengrid returns HTTP Error 400: Bad Request

Tags: django, sendgrid, django-email

I am following [this link](https://sendgrid.com/docs/for-developers/sending-email/personalizations/) to send emails from Django using SendGrid. If my email address in **cc** and **to_email** is same, it returns **HTTP Error 400: Bad Request**. But it works fine if the email address is different. Did anyone solve this problem before? I need to add cc while sending an email from Django whether the email address is the same or different. Thanks in advance.

```
sg = SendGridAPIClient(development.EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD)
cc_email = str(ImagingCenter.objects.get(institute_id=user.center_id).email)
from_email = development.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL
to_email = to_email
data = {
         "personalizations": [{
                        "to": [{
                            "email": to_email
                        }],
                        "cc": [
                            {
                                "email": cc_email
                            }
                        ],
                        "subject": "CC Email Testing"
                    }
                ],
                "from": {
                    "email": from_email
                },
                "content": [
                    {
                        "type": "text/html",
                        "value": html_message
                    }
                ]
            }
            response = sg.client.mail.send.post(request_body=data)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Sendgrid does not allow for duplicate emails among the to, cc and bcc fields**.

That is also wrote in Sendgrid Personalizations Doc:

> All of the recipients in a single personalization object (specified in
> the to, cc, or bcc fields) will see the same email, as defined by the
> data in that personalization. Because of this, SendGrid does not allow
> duplicate email addresses among these three recipient arrays in a
> single personalization.

See also [BadRequest if same email address is in the To & BCC fields.
#678](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-csharp/issues/678#issuecomment-373173582)

Comment: I would upvote this answer 20 times if i could. Just wasted an afternoon >.<

Answer (score 0):

github link return 404 now...But this is a actual problem. IF the same email address in to/cc/bcc the api return a BAD REQUEST.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).