# 400 Bad Request when adding CC for send email SendGrid JSON in Azure Runbook

Tags: json, azure, runbook

I'm using this as part of the runbook in Azure. The email works fine if I'm only using the To field for emails

```
$jsonRequest = [ordered]@{
personalizations= @(@{to = @(@{email = "$To"})
subject = "$SubJect" })

                        from = @{email = "$From"}
                        content = @( @{ type = "text/HTML"
                                    value = "$Body" }
                        )} | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 10
```

Invoke-RestMethod   -Uri "https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/mail/send" -Method Post -Headers $headers -Body $jsonRequest

However if I'm adding the CC field, then I get 400 Bad request error. Is there another way to incorporate CC into the same request?

```
$jsonRequest = [ordered]@{
                        personalizations= @(@{to = @(@{email =  "$To"})
                            cc = @{email = "$cc"}
                            subject = "$SubJect" })
                            
                            from = @{email = "$From"}
                            content = @( @{ type = "text/HTML"
                                        value = "$Body" }
                            )} | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 10
Invoke-RestMethod   -Uri "https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/mail/send" -Method Post -Headers $headers -Body $jsonRequest
```

Comment: You can refer to [Azure runbook script to send mail using PowerShell and SendGrid](https://www.sharepointwidgets.com/2021/01/azure-runbook-script-to-send-mail-using.html) and [Django: adding cc in email with sengrid returns HTTP Error 400: Bad Request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66282325/django-adding-cc-in-email-with-sengrid-returns-http-error-400-bad-request)

Comment: Hi DeepDave-MT, thank you so much for providing the links.  We have tried the script from the first link but still getting the 400 Bad request error.  It looks like SendGrid gives the error when we have both $to and $cc in the personalization part.

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare the variable that handles the 'cc' in the parameters part.
This worked for me:

```
function Send-EmailWithSendGrid {
Param
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [string] $From,
 
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [String] $To,

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [String] $cc,

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [string] $ApiKey,

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [string] $Subject,

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [string] $Body

    )

$headers = @{}
$headers.Add("Authorization","Bearer $apiKey")
$headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json")
$jsonRequest = [ordered]@{personalizations= @(@{to = @(@{email =  "$To"})
                            cc = @(@{email =  "$cc"})
                                subject = "$SubJect" })
                                from = @{email = "$From"}
                                content = @( @{ type = "text/html"
                                            value = "$Body" }

                                )} | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 10
    Invoke-RestMethod   -Uri "https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/mail/send" -Method Post -Headers $headers -Body $jsonRequest 
    }
$From = "youremail@domain.com"
$To = "abc@gmail.com"
$cc = "def@gmail.com"
$APIKEY = "YouAPIkey"

$Subject = "Test"
$Body = "Body here"

                   
Send-EmailWithSendGrid -from $from -to $To -cc $cc -ApiKey $APIKEY -Body $Body -Subject $Subject
```